# Android sh: rndis0: not found

Tags: android

I'm running the Android Terminal Emulator on my Samsung Galaxy Grand. And I am trying to set up USB reverse tethering with some tutorials online, though I ran into some problems. When I type in:

```
# netcfg
```

It shows "rndis0" in the UP state and the rest in the down state. And when I type the following, I get the given error.

```
# netcfg rndis0 dhcp
sh: rndis0: not found
```

The same happens when I try to use "ifconfig".

```
# ifconfig rndis0
rndis0: ip 192.168.42.129 mask 255.255.255.0 flags [up broadcast running multicast]
```

But for:

```
# ifconfig rndis0 192.168.42.129 netmask 255.255.255.0
sh: rndis0: not found
```

Why does this happen?